# Issue in Dynamic Routing after domain name in Angular 4+

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-router

In my Angular 4 project I have a container component at route:

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent},
    { path: 'pages/:page-handle', component: StaticpagesComponent },
    { path: 'blog/:blog-handle', component: StaticpagesComponent },
    { path: 'idx', component: ListingComponent },
    { path: 'area/:area-name', component: AreadetailComponent },
    { path: 'zip-code/:zip-name', component: ZipdetailComponent },
    { path: ':agent-handle', component:AgentComponent },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
];
```

So i want to acccess different component after domain name
For example

- http://localhost:8080/:zip-name then should call ZipdetailComponent
- http://localhost:8080/:area-name then should call AreadetailComponent
- http://localhost:8080/:page-handle then should call
  StaticpagesComponent

Issue: any name after domain goes into following route:

```
 { path: ':agent-handle', component:AgentComponent },
```

anyone know how can i solve?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On basis of routes you have define,It should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/zipcode/:zip-name  
http://localhost:8080/area/:area-name  
http://localhost:8080/pages/:page-handle
```

Comment: you dont need anything to change.For Example:if you run localhost:8080/zip-code/27511 , it will automatically goes in ZipDetailComponent

Comment: Hi sorry my friend 
my be i did mistake in writing
but i want like
http://localhost:8080/:zip-name
http://localhost:8080/:area-name
then how can i get different component

Comment: That might not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the routes matter. You should define the `''` route in the end, before the wildcard match, so that it matches if nothing else is matching.

From the angular routes documentation.

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

[Source](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

Comment: Yes @Ankit you are right but <br>
{ path: ':page-handle', component: StaticpagesComponent }, 
{ path: ':agent-handle', component:AgentComponent }, 
then always it calls first StaticpagesComponent 
then how can call AgentComponent ?
if i am pass http://localhost:8080/:agent-handle

Comment: Then you should create your routes like `agent/:handle` and `page/:handle`.